# Can we have an XKCD bot?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I was on SuperUser chat the other day, and they had an [XKCD Bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-313/xkcd).

Can our chat have access to that bot? I'm sure a lot of AU users are followers of XKCD.

Comment: Just for accuracy's sake, its a feed, not a bot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm against adding non-relevant feeds.  It's a chat room, not an RSS reader.

Comment: XKCD is always relevant, though...

Answer (score 4):

Seeing a new XKCD pop in might be fun, but since I recently had to ignore the UL bot/feed - I'm not sure Anyone - including myself needs to say "Let's add some noise..."

note:  Oli's answer got a +1 from me.

additional note:  I note this when I post an answer, but I really back someone else's...  and I think mine can add something to the conversation.

Comment: The UL bot being the one which shows questions tagged Ubuntu on UL?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.